# Timeout to search network in Android 7

Tags: android, android-api-levels, android-connectivitymanager

I have an old android device which is running Android 7. I know it is quite old, but is needed to be used in work. The device "seems" would be disconnected for a long time when the available network is not searchable. I'm wondering if there is any timeout to "search network" like

```
Retry Attempt 1: 1 second
Retry Attempt 2: 5 seconds
Retry Attempt 3: 30 seconds
Retry Attempt 4: 60 seconds
Retry Attempt 5: 5 mins
Retry Attempt 6: 30 mins
```

Cuz I find [Android Developer Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback#onUnavailable()) have some disconnected functions that would be triggered due to the timeout. Or, any functions I can take a look to investigate it? Thanks.

or `will it also be possible that the device register a wrong network (success), but automatically timeout when no internet available for a long time?`